# changing bios language of ProBook 6450b

Tags: sysbios

I want to install window form USB to my system (hp ProoBook 6450b), but it doesn't booted with usb, therefore i want to change boot setup with biose, but i don't understand the bios language of my system.So please help me to change my system bios language to english.

Answer (score 2):

BIOS code is programmed into EEPROM chips that are almost positively too small to support multiple language display. You need to flash it with an English BIOS for the same computer, or find someone who can translate for you.. If is it possible then you can update your BIOS via internet.

Comment: kuldeep thanks for your interest, but i don't know how to change flash EEPROM. can you help me more. thanks

Comment: Maybe you can flash the BIOS with an English one? Never had this problem myself. Every computer I used had an English BIOS regardless of the language of the OS. @ Anwar Said